# Restructure word list into two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pandas-groupby

If I have columns of lists, is there a pandas function that lets me split each word which is separated by a comma to return two new columns, one column represents the first word which can not connect by itself and the second column represents the connected word. In general the idea is to create a word table of the different words and compare them together in two columns. The following table is used for a better interpretation of the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

r1=['tag1','tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']

df=pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['text'])
```

Desired Outcome, first column shows the first word, the second column represents the connected word. This process is also vice versa, for the next words in the lists.:

```
col1  |  col2
--------------
tag1  |  tag2
tag1  |  tag3    
tag1  |  tag4
tag2  |  tag1
tag2  |  tag3
tag2  |  tag4
tag3  |  tag1
tag3  |  tag2
tag3  |  tag4
tag4  |  tag1
tag4  |  tag2
tag4  |  tag3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.permutations`

**Demo:**

```
from itertools import permutations
import pandas as pd

r1=['tag1','tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(permutations(r1,2)), columns=['col1','col2'])
#df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in permutations(r1,2)], columns=['col1','col2'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    col1  col2
0   tag1  tag2
1   tag1  tag3
2   tag1  tag4
3   tag2  tag1
4   tag2  tag3
5   tag2  tag4
6   tag3  tag1
7   tag3  tag2
8   tag3  tag4
9   tag4  tag1
10  tag4  tag2
11  tag4  tag3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For this example it works fine. I have some strings, where the construction looks as follow: r1=['tag1 ,tag2, tag3, tag4']. Can I convert it as the example above (each tag is convert as a unique string)?

Comment: `r1[0].split(",")` ?

Comment: I only receive a list of all words like [tag1, tag3, tag4 ] for col1 and for col2 like [tag2, tag3, tag4]

Comment: Can you post exactly how your input is in your question?

Comment: like this r1=['tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4] (column of dataframe)